# Сортировка таблицы при динамическом добавлении строк с использованием jQuery tablesorter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте. Хочу сортировать строки в таблице с помощью jQuery tablesorter. С обычной статической таблицей все работает(она в коде с id myTable1), вот когда элементы добавляются динамически сортировка не работает (это показано в коде на таблице с id myTable2). Заранее благодарен за помощь.

```js
$(function(){
        $("#myTable1").tablesorter();
    });


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#clickme').click(function(){
        var key = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
        $('<tr><td>'+key+'</td></tr>').prependTo($('#tbod1'));
    });
});

$(function(){
            $("#myTable2").tablesorter();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<table id="myTable1" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bach</td>
        <td>Frank</td>
    </tr>
   
    </tbody>
</table>
<br><br>

<table class="tablesorter" id="myTable2">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbod1"></tbody>
</table>

<div id='clickme'>Click here</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот плагин кэширует строки, которые потом сортирует, поэтому при запуске он запомнил, что строк не было - и фактически сортировал пустой массив.

Для обновления кэша нужно послать соответствующее событие:

```
$("#myTable2").trigger('updateCache');
```

Пример:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myTable1").tablesorter();
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clickme').click(function() {
    var key = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    $('<tr><td>' + key + '</td></tr>').prependTo($('#tbod1'));
    $("#myTable2").trigger('updateCache');
  });

});

$(function() {
  $("#myTable2").tablesorter();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<table id="myTable1" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bach</td>
      <td>Frank</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>

<table class="tablesorter" id="myTable2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbod1"></tbody>
</table>

<div id='clickme'>Click here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы сортируете таблицу при первой загрузке странице. А потом динамически добавляете данные.
Ваше событие нужно доработать — добавить сортировку таблицы после добавления новой строки.

Пример:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#clickme').click(function(){
        var key = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
        $('<tr><td>'+key+'</td></tr>').prependTo($('#tbod1'));
        $("#myTable2").tablesorter();
    });
});
```

Comment: вызов `.tablesorter()` - это не сортировка таблицы, это инициализация плагина